# Change value for anonymous property of type string

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I'm working on an app written in WPF, the code is written in C#.
I have a question mark icon which when pressed suppose to set content to specific label.
The label content is binding to a property in the view model, lets call it 'NoneLegend'.
I want that property to clear itself after 5 second so I have a utility class that suppose to manage that. Inside that class I wrote an anonymous method that gets any type of property.
My question is how do I set that property to string.empty?
The method looks like this:

```
public static void EmptyStringAfterXseconds<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
        {
            var propertyInfo = ((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member as PropertyInfo;
            if (propertyInfo == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The lambda expression 'property' should point to a valid Property");
            }
            else
            {
                var t = propertyInfo.GetType();
                propertyInfo.SetValue(null, "");
            }
        }
```

And I'm calling it like that:

```
NoneLegend = "Bla bla...";
Utils.EmptyStringAfterXseconds(() => NoneLegend);
```

Comment: I think you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and call the PropertyChanged(nameof(NoneLegend)) to have the changes reflected in the field.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is not part of the solution here I'm afraid. The goal is to change the value after 5 seconds from a generic method.

Comment: I made an example for you. Will post is soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. I'm a bit worried about the `new ResetAfterTime()` call. Don't know if the instance is around long enough. It might be collected by the Garbage Collector before the Timer fires. Would have to think about that but it seems to work fine.

A Notifier class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class PropertyNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        // The view automatically fills the PropertyChanged event
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

The Viewmodel:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class ViewModel : PropertyNotifier
    {
        public ViewModel(string legend)
        {
            Legend = legend;
        }

        private string _Legend;

        /// <summary>
        /// Here's where the magic happens
        /// </summary>
        public string Legend
        {
            get => _Legend;
            set
            {
                _Legend = value;
                new ResetAfterTime<string>(this, () => Legend, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And your enhanced routine:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class ResetAfterTime<T>
            where T : class
    {
        Timer _timer;
        PropertyInfo _propertyInfo;
        PropertyNotifier _notifier;
        int _due;

        public ResetAfterTime(PropertyNotifier notifier, Expression<Func<T>> property, T value, int due = 3000)
        {
            _notifier = notifier;
            _propertyInfo = ((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member as PropertyInfo;
            _due = due;

            if (_propertyInfo == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The lambda expression 'property' should point to a valid Property");
            }
            else
            {
                if (value != default)
                {
                    StartTimer();
                }
            }
        }
        private void StartTimer()
        {
            _timer = new Timer(MakeDisappear, null, _due, _due);
        }

        private void StopTimer()
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
            _timer = null;
        }

        private void MakeDisappear(object state)
        {
            SetValue(null);
            StopTimer();
        }

        private void SetValue(object value)
        {
            var t = _propertyInfo.GetType();
            _propertyInfo.SetValue(_notifier, value);
            _notifier.NotifyPropertyChanged(_propertyInfo.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution Paul, Thanks a lot! Since I'm using my own ObservableObject which handles all of my NotifyPropertyChanged events I hade to customize your code a little in order to match my structure but after that everything works like a charm! This is pure generic code and I can use it along all legends cross my app. Thank you very very much for investing in such a beautiful effort!!! :-)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

For the binding in the view to know what has changed you need to notify it about that change. The INotifyProperyChanged interface was designed for that purpose. In the code below in the ViewModel this interface is implemented.

I've created a simple WPF program. Here's the MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label x:Name="Legend" Content="{Binding Legend}"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new ViewModel("Text should disappear");
        }
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Timer LegendTimer;

        public ViewModel(string legend)
        {
            Legend = legend;
        }

        private void StartLegendTimer()
        {
            LegendTimer = new Timer(MakeDisappear, null, 3000, 3000);
        }

        private void StopLegendTimer()
        {
            LegendTimer.Dispose();
            LegendTimer = null;
        }

        private void MakeDisappear(object state)
        {
            Legend = string.Empty;
            StopLegendTimer();
        }

        private string _Legend;

        /// <summary>
        /// Here's where the magic happens
        /// </summary>
        public string Legend
        {
            get => _Legend;
            set
            {
                // Each time the value is set ...
                _Legend = value;
                // we notify the view that a value has changed
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Legend));
                // If the value is not null or empty
                if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                {
                    // We start the time
                    StartLegendTimer();
                }
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        // The view automatically fills the PropertyChanged event
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Paul, Thank you very very much for the beautiful code and effort. I must say I am well familiar with wpf and the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and already thought of that option. The problem is: How can we handle multiple properties? Imaging you have 10 legends for 10 labels on your xaml, each is placed in different location and targeting something else. This is why I thought about anonymous type at the first place. Do you have any idea how to solve it? Your timer call directly to a specific property and I need it to be pure generic.

Comment: BTW, My ViewModel already contains INotifyPropertyChanged, I can't see how is it possible to work without it :-)